# How I can store in a data frame the forecast result of several time series forecasts in R

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, forecasting, arima

I have a large set of data to work with, over 30k products, with the demand data of the last 60 months. I need a forecast model for each product for the next 24 months.
In my data frame each column is a product and the rows represent the demand for the respective month

So far using a subset of my data frame I was able to forecast each product using auto arima. However, I'm struggling in create a new data frame with the historical data plus the forecast results.

The code bellow is working, I need help to store the forecast result in a data frame with the historical data and later export the result in a csv file

```
teste <- base_und[,1:4] 
lst1 <- lapply (teste, ts, start = 1, end = 60) 
output <- lapply(lst1, function(x) forecast(auto.arima(x,seasonal = TRUE)))
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to give a minimal reproducible example, see [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

you need to use rbind() to bind your historical and forecasted data.
First create historical points data frame then in last

```
data_frame = rbind(data_frame,forecasted_dataframe).
```

Hope answer to your question.

Comment: forecast produces a nested list which is the problem.  Extracting $mean from the forecast gives the mean prediction, but then it resets the index